# How to change id to uuid?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `shops` where `username` = csesumonpro and `id` 5d4cb970-197d-41db-90e1-26988d543935)

how to change id to uuid when execute query? i am using uuid in my model replace of id i already defined

```
 protected $primaryKey = 'uuid'; // in my model
```

Show above error when use unique email  validation, unique email validation execute a query query autonomic capture id but i need uuid .otherwise everything is ok.

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email,'.$user->id  // validation code
```

Comment: Wouldn't `'unique:users,email,'.$user->id` be `'unique:users,email,'.$user->uuid`??

Comment: i have already changed id to uuid but same error

Comment: Have you thought about creating your own custom rule in this instance?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique

Comment: no @thisiskelvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the uuid column name as you are not using numerical IDs.

So it should read:

```php
'email' => 'unique:users,email,'.$user->uuid.',uuid'
```